# adding an 'all' category to my category links

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

The index/home page to my Wordpress website is all my posts. I use the following code to list all the categories on the page in the header.

```
<h3><?php wp_list_categories(); ?></h3>
```

This lists all the categories I have, and it links to the archive page, displaying the posts from each category.  On this page, I want to add and highlight an 'ALL' section since on this page all the posts are visible.

Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `show_option_all` argument with value of link text. See [Codex: wp_list_categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories).

> **show_option_all**
>
> (string) When "style" is set to "list", setting this parameter outputs a link to all categories. The default value is "NULL" (all category link not displayed).

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'show_option_all' => 'All posts'
);
?>

<h3><?php wp_list_categories($args); ?></h3>
```

"All posts" link will have class `cat-item-all` on it's `<li>`. So you can easily highlight it with CSS.

For example:

```
li.cat-item-all a{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: That works great, is there a way I can highlight it when on my home page?